# How to remove the two duplicate values

Tags: php

How to remove the two duplicate values

Example I have the variable 1 $help_brother:

```
$help_brother = '30,45,12,13,14,15';
```

And the variable 2 Force World:

```
$force_world = '45,12,15';
```

The result must be:

Result: `'30,13,14';`

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the result

```
$help_brother = '30,45,12,13,14,15';
$force_world = '45,12,15';

$help_brother_array = explode(',', $help_brother);
$force_world_array = explode(',', $force_world);


$Result = array_diff($help_brother_array, $force_world_array);
echo implode(",",$Result);
```

You can get the following result.

If it helps then upvode the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much